# Fayet-Iliopoulos terms

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, supersymmetry, superspace-formalism

It is mentioned in first page of [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/0904.1159) paper by Seiberg and Komargodski that the Lagrangian in superspace of a $U(1)$ gauge SUSY theory with FI terms is not gauge invariant. However, the FI terms in superspace is 
$$
\xi \int d^4  \theta V
$$ 
where $V$ is a vector superfield. Now if we do a gauge transformation on $V$, i.e.,
$$
V\longrightarrow V+ i (\Phi-\bar{\Phi})
$$ 
the FI term remains invariant since
$$
\int  d^4  \theta \Phi=\int  d^4  \theta \bar{\Phi}=0.
$$

So what is the source of the gauge non-invariance in superspace ?

Answer (score 1):

I think what they mean is FI-term is not gauge invariant under the full gauge symmetry of the theory, but under this remaining gauge freedom after WZ gauge, which is $U(1)$.

Comment: well seen ... don't you cite the 2nd paragraph of the introduction from the 3rd sentence ?

Comment: yes, but also this is well known that adding FI restricts YM theory to $G = U(1)$.

Comment: it was to answer the last question ... But you said the main thing to the OP

Comment: I understand that the supercurrent is gauge invariant only under the WZ gauge but the above FI term in superspace is invariant under the full gauge symmetry. Can't see the WZ restriction in superspace.

Comment: @Axion from where comes the exact form of the F terms you used ? from which model precisely ( and book ) ?

Comment: How can FI term be invariant under the full gauge symmetry? FI term is $D$, just $D$, which is the last component of a vector multiplet. $S_{FI} = \xi \int d^4 x D$. How can you generalize this to YM? The way you obtain this action is that you take a real multiplet, and consider it's highest component $D$ as an action. Then you impose WZ condition. This takes four components of the real multiplet including the auxiliary vector and the auxiliary scalar $D$, and turns it into a vector multiplet which is determined by $G = U(1)$. Thus you get FI terms, which is the highest component of vec. mult.

Comment: @JohnDoe Isn't the full gauge symmetry is simply given by $V\rightarrow V+i(\Phi-\bar{\Phi})$ under which the FI term in superspace is invariant?